# Detecting successful read stream open

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, methodology

I'm implementing cache for static serving middleware for Express.js, which works as follows — when request comes, middleware first tries to serve file from filesystem, and if there is none, file is fetched from upstream and stored in file system.

Problem is I don't know how to properly detect “cache hit” event.

```
staticMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
    // try to read file from fs
    filename = urlToFilename(req.url);
    stream = fs.createReadStream(filename);

    // cache miss - file not found
    stream.on('error', function() {
        console.log('miss ' + req.url);

        // get file from upstream, store it into fs and serve as response
        stream = fetchFromUpstream(url);
        stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename));
        stream.pipe(res);
    });

    // cache hit - file is being read
    I_DONT_KNOW_WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE(function() {
        console.log('hit ' + req.url);

        stream.pipe(res);
    });
}
```

So, basically, how can I detect succesful file reading? If I listen to 'data' event, I guess I miss first chunk of data. If I just `pipe()` it to response, response stream gets closed on error, and I can't serve it with fetched data, and this approach really lacks flexibility. I wonder if there is way to listen for event like `fdcreated` or `opened` or similar, or way to push back data I've got in `data` event, so it will be resent in next `data` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `createReadStream` returns a ReadableStream which also  an event `open`. You can add an event handler for the [open](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_event_open) event so you will know when the resource is valid before piping:

```
stream.on('open', function() {
    console.log('hit ' + req.url);
    stream.pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: As I've mentioned, if I do `stream.once('data', function(chunk) { /* hit! */ stream.pipe(req); });`, I lose first chunk of data, because `pipe()` attaches its own listener for `data` after first chunk was passed to me.

Comment: @modchan - my bad :) There's an open even you can attach to, check my edit.

Comment: Oh, now I see, I've looked into a wrong place for this event — I thought something like `open` event should be part of `ReadableStream` spec, not fs-specific. Thanks!