# Both `open` and `error` at same time with fs.createReadStream() and EISDIR

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

While implementing simple static serving middleware, I stumbled across the fact in following code:

```
fs = require('fs');
util = require('util');

stream = fs.createReadStream('/');
stream.on('open', function(fd) { console.log('opened! ' + util.inspect(fd)); });
stream.on('error', function(err) { console.log('error! ' + util.inspect(err)); });
```

both `open` and `error` events are emitted when argument is directory!

> ```
> $ node test.js 
> opened! 11
> error! { [Error: EISDIR, read] errno: 28, code: 'EISDIR' }
> ```

I assumed I have either `open` or `error`, never both at same time.

What is graceful way to distinguish between *good `open`* and *bad `open`* without resorting to explicitly testing `fd` with `stat` to be directory? Are there other similar cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended with following approach:

1. `fs.open(path, 'r', function(err, fd) { ... })` to get file descriptor `fd`;
2. `fs.fstat(fd, function(err, stats) { ... })` to `stat` on given file descriptor;
3. `stats.isDirectory()` to handle `EISDIR` case;
4. `stream = fs.createReadStream(null, { fd: fd, flags: 'r' })` to finally get readable file stream;

This way I protect myself from possible interchanging file with directory and vice versa after it was checked but before it was opened, as even if someone does trickery its file descriptor will still be valid.

Comment: Note: While this approach used to work great, it no longer seems to work in Node 8  (see https://github.com/mikermcneil/machinepack-fs/commit/7ae0abf7af16e23a979e32fd6754abb6808b2f51)

Comment: @mikermcneil, could you please clarify what exactly broke? I have just repeated this on Node 8.6.0, and it worked flawlessly on both macOS 10.12.4 and Linux 4.9.49.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Readable Stream in Node, the code will attempt to open the file and read the contents (if a `fd` is not provided).  You can see that via the code:

Calling `createReadStream()` creates a `ReadStream` object, which will call `this.open()` if `fd` is not a number ([link to source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/03e9f84933fe610b04b107cf1f83d17485e8906e/lib/fs.js#L1492-L1493)):

```
if (!util.isNumber(this.fd))
  this.open();
```

This calls `fs.open`, which on a directory I'm guessing opens the directory?  (This is a bit weird as to why this is allowed to work without error, but the code eventually hits the native binding layer and continues on.)  With it open, the code emits the "open" event and begins to read the contents of the file ([link to source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/03e9f84933fe610b04b107cf1f83d17485e8906e/lib/fs.js#L1516-L1518)):

```
ReadStream.prototype.open = function() {
  var self = this;
  fs.open(this.path, this.flags, this.mode, function(er, fd) {
    if (er) {
      if (self.autoClose) {
        self.destroy();
      }
      self.emit('error', er);
      return;
    }

    self.fd = fd;
    self.emit('open', fd);
    // start the flow of data.
    self.read();
  });
};
```

It's during the call to `fs.read` which causes the error, which is sent to the `ReadStream`'s callback `onRead` ([link to source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/03e9f84933fe610b04b107cf1f83d17485e8906e/lib/fs.js#L1561-L1574)):

```
function onread(er, bytesRead) {
  if (er) {
    if (self.autoClose) {
      self.destroy();
    }
    self.emit('error', er);
```

So because the `createReadStream` call immediately opens and begins reading the contents of the file (if a file descriptor isn't passed), the events will be emitted as you've seen.  First the `open` event, then attempting to read the file, that fails, and the `error` event is emitted.

As this is a [readable stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable), you might want to consider listening for the `data` event instead of the `open` event to judge if this is an acceptable file, since you are reading immediately.  Something similar to this:

```
fs = require('fs');
util = require('util');

stream = fs.createReadStream('/');
stream.on('data', function(chunk) { console.log('data! ' + chunk.toString()); });
stream.on('error', function(err) { console.log('error! ' + util.inspect(err)); });
```

In tests, you'll hit `data` on a file and `error` on a directory.

Comment: Listening for `data` event has a drawback — you can no longer `pipe` stream, because of first data chunk to be lost, unless handled specifically — that was point of my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/q/24349896/472695, where I was recommended to use `open` to track 'cache hit'.

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't know that was your intention. With that then, you're probably going to have to `fs.stat()` the file/directory first to understand what it is, prior to running `fs.createReadStream()` since it will attempt to read the file if no file descriptor is passed.

Comment: yup, and that is actually an antipattern according to node.js docs — `fs.exists() is an anachronism and exists only for historical reasons. There should almost never be a reason to use it in your own code. In particular, checking if a file exists before opening it is an anti-pattern that leaves you vulnerable to race conditions: another process may remove the file between the calls to fs.exists() and fs.open(). Just open the file and handle the error when it's not there`. Isn't doing `fs.stat()` before opening the same bad as doing `fs.exists()`?

Comment: You can choose to just use `fs.createReadStream` and ignore the `fs.stat` call, then listen for errors and abandon the code when it happens, but you'll be in the same situation as you started.  I understand the thinking in not using `fs.exists`, but you're not checking that the file exists, but if it's a file or directory.  I'm not sure how often a file changes to a directory and vice-versa, so wouldn't think the errors you'd hit would be that often (if it was to change).  Even if you put the `fs.stat` first, you'd still have the same error logic in your `fs.createReadStream`

Comment: `var sentReply = false;
var pass = ('stream').PassThrough
replyStream = new pass;
stream.on('data', function(data){
  replyStream.write(data);
  if (!sentReply){
    // do your stuff here. Use replyStream for response to browser.
    // remember to send the last data on 'end'
  }
  sentReply = true;
}
`